# Javascript event on frame loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, frame, jquery-events

I can't quite work out how I can get a frame being notified when another frame has changed.

```
<frameset rows="*,50">
    <frame id="main_frame" src="mainframe" frameborder="0" name="main_frame">
    <frame id="footer" src="footer" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" noresize="noresize" name="footer">
</frameset>
```

The footer frame needs to set some values in mainframe once it's loaded. If the user loads another page, this setup has to occur again. In the footer, I'd like to have an event on when the main frame has completed loading (every time it changes).

Is this possible (perhaps even with jQuery)?

Comment: try <frameset onload="foo()" ... />

Comment: I guess that would also work. I've put the onload into the main frame's frame definition (as I want to signal when it has changed). Where would you put foo() in your case? It needs to call a method that's residing in an included javascript of the footer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below is just an example; I used jQuery's load event, and this code would be placed in your `main_frame` frame.  It gets the parent of the frames, then the children frames as per the array.  Hopefully you can extrapolate it into what you need.

In this example, it is assumed that the `yourValue` variable is a global variable in either of your frames.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).load(function (){
        window.parent.frames[0].yourValue = 4; // change values of main frame
        window.parent.frames[1].yourValue = 4; // change values of footer frame
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure why, but the event doesn't get triggered. I put it into the main frame...

Comment: @user1230724 I've altered my answer, please see if it works for you.  I've used the above, so it should.  Also make sure you are loading jquery.